# flash not showing up

Tags: flash

So I have this basic html page which has flash in it.
This page was generated by flash software
when I clicked the publish option.

If I open the page in chrome I can see the flash video playing.
[image: Image of the file when I open it]

However if I use localhost or my hosting provider it does not
render the flash file. I double checked all the src files
but I can't seems to find the problem. Please see the actual
file here http://www.iamvishal.com/pureecn/assets/slide/test.html

my swf file is at

http://www.iamvishal.com/pureecn/assets/slide/test.swf

Answer (score 0):

Use [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed swf on your webpage: there are lots of problems with other ways.

Comment: I tried using the swfObject and I seem to have the same issue. It did not help. please see file http://www.iamvishal.com/pureecn/assets/slide/Untitled-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the html page and the test.swf link. They both look the same - blank white.  So they are showing up but don't have any content.  I think your problem is that the image isn't loading - see if the link to the image is correct.  And add some background color to the swf or another drawing object to test this if you need to.

```
this.graphics.beginFill(0x333366);
this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
this.graphics.endfill();
```